# Microsoft CRM 4.0 form attribute mysteriously read-only

Tags: dynamics-crm

I've inherited a customization of Campaign Response in which the Customer attribute is read-only on the form (in both create and update modes), and I can't figure out why. The form has no OnLoad javascript, the attribute "customer" (which is a partylist) is Searchable, and the field-level behavior for the attribute on the form has "Field is read-only" unchecked.  The attribute is read-only even for the System Administrator, so it's not an authorization issue.

What else could be making this field read-only?

Thanks,

Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After giving up on Microsoft's support, which was absolutely abysmal, I paid an outside consultant to look into this.

He compared my exported customization to his, and found that, in my exported XML, the Customer field in the Campaign Response form had no LookupTypes, whereas his had 3 LookupTypes:

```xml
<LookupType id="f953c2fa-2241-db11-898a-0007e9e17ebd">1</LookupType>
<LookupType id="fa53c2fa-2241-db11-898a-0007e9e17ebd">2</LookupType>
<LookupType id="fb53c2fa-2241-db11-898a-0007e9e17ebd">4</LookupType>
```

LookupTypes 1, 2, and 4 were exactly what should be there for Account, Contact, and Lead for the Customer of a Campaign Response.

So I added those 3 lines to my XML, imported and published, and now the Customer is enabled and apparently fine.

I would love to know how these LookupTypes could have gone missing in the first place.  But at least I've got the default functionality back.

Answer (score 0):

First I'd make sure that entity is published. Could be that someone made the change, and then didn't publish the entity.

Second, it is possible that there could be some unsupported changes to the environment. Off the top of my head, they could be attaching javascript to the form via an http module, or modifying the form html by making it locked down, again through an http module. I'd check for any non-native http modules added to CRM's web.config, and I'd also poke around to see if there were any entities that look like they'd be configuration entities for locking/hiding fields. We often do something like that, though in a supported way.

Comment: Thanks Matt.

Yes, we have published the entity (repeatedly).  The only http modules in the web.config are MapOrg and CrmAuthentication, both from Microsoft.  I'm not sure what a configuration entity would look like.  The types I see when I list entities under Customization are Client Extensions, Customizable Entity, Security Role, Settings, Templates, and Workflow.  Where should I look for a configuration entity that might be locking/hiding this field?

Thanks!

Comment: I was thinking there might be an entity working in tandem with an http module or something... it would be a customizable, custom entity if they used this method.

Comment: Hi Matt.  I could find nothing along the lines you suggested.

I did find however, that form field is not simply read-only, but it is disabled.  I don't know whether that helps.

I've had an incident open with Microsoft for a week, and they too are stumped.  There must be some internals-savvy person there that could walk through our installation to figure out what is causing this, but I don't know whether I'll be able to find that person.

Thanks for your advice.